# bootstrap using client side less gives compile errors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using client side less with bootstrap but can't get it to parse without errors.

I get "error NameError is undefined" messages for classes and variables which have already been processed.

I individually import the core variables, reset, core reset and the selected components that I need:

```
<link href="less/variables.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/mixins.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/normalize.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/print.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/scaffolding.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/type.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/code.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/grid.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/tables.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/forms.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/buttons.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/navbar.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<link href="less/navs.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  less = { env: 'development' };
</script>
<script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All the less files are parsed but only the first four are generated. The rest say:

```
NameError: .clearfix is undefined in navs.less on line 13, column 3:
NameError: variable @padding-base-vertical is undefined in buttons.less on line 20, column 16:
```

I can see that .clearfix is defined in mixins.less and @padding-base-vertical is defined in variables.less which are both parsed and generated without errors.

Please give me a clue what I am getting wrong!

Comment: You should not link these files individually into your HTML (variables and mixins defined in one linked less file are not visible in another). The correct way to use all this is to link to bootstrap.less which imports all these at the LESS level.

Comment: Many thanks, seven-phases-max, that worked perfectly. Mark